# IF/AND Function in Excel returning 0 when conditions are met

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

So just like the title says, my formula is returning some of the outputs, but for others, it simply outputs 0, which is the value if false. Perhaps I have too many nested AND functions. Any analysis and help would be appreciated!

Formaula: =IF(E3="O-1",AND(C3>=3,C3<=3.49)*800,IF(E3="O-3",AND(C3>=3.75)*700,IF(E3="O-2",AND(C3>=3.5,C3<=3.74)*800,IF(E3="O-3",AND(C3>=3.5,C3<=3.74)*500,IF(E3="O-1",AND(C3>=3.5,C3<=3.74)*1100,IF(E3="O-1",AND(C3>=3.75)*1300,IF(E3="Presidential",4900,IF(E3="O-2",AND(C3>=3,C3<=3.49)*700,IF(E3="O-2",AND(C3>=3.75)*1000,IF(E3="O-3",AND(C3>=3,C3<=3.49)*400,0))))))))))

Comment: Welcome to Super User. You need to show us examples of `E3` and `C3` values that don't return what you expect, and specify what you expect the formula to return for these values. Otherwise, there's no way for anyone to know what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you would

- explain what sort of logic tree you are trying to implement, and
- give an example of conditions under which the formula evaluates to a value that isn’t what you want
  (and say what value you want).

Also, a common technique to debug problems like this is to simplify what you have until either

- it can be read and understood at a glance, or
- the problem goes away (in which case you know that
  the last simplifying change you made eliminated the code that has the problem).

Your formula begins

```
=IF(E3="O-1", AND(C3>=3,C3<=3.49)*800, …
```

This mean that, if `E3` equals `"O-1"`, the expression evaluates to `AND(C3>=3,C3<=3.49)*800`. 
If `C3` is less than `3`, `C3>=3` is FALSE. 
If `C3` is greater than `3.49`, `C3<=3.49` is FALSE. 
Either way, `AND(C3>=3,C3<=3.49)` evaluates to FALSE, which is numerically equal to 0,
so `AND(C3>=3,C3<=3.49)*800` is zero.

So, if `E3` equals `"O-1"` and `C3` is less than `3`,
it is correct for this formula to evaluate to 0. 
(This is just one of ***many*** compound conditions that lead to this result.) 
Does this match your situation?

Also, your formula *really **really*** doesn’t make sense. 
It contains

```
=IF(…, IF(E3="O-3", …, IF(E3="O-3", …
```

The second test for `E3="O-3"` will never be satisfied. 
(And that is not the only redundant/unreachable part of your expression.)